# Windows 10 Universal App Interacting with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, win-universal-app

*--html*

```
 <form method='post' id="theForm" onsubmit="showToast();">
            <input type='text' id="username" name='username' placeholder='Username'>
            <input type='password' id='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'>
     <input type='submit' value='Login'>

            <!-- /login -->
        </form>
```

--javascript--

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
        function showToast() {
            var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
            var passwords = document.getElementById("password").value;
            window.external.notify(user.toString() + "-" +         passwords.toString());
        }

     </script>
```

*--code when javascript called*

```
 public MainPage()
    {
                this.InitializeComponent();
                WebView.ScriptNotify += webView_ScriptNotify;
    }



 private void  webView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
                {

                    string commandStr = e.Value.ToString();
        }
```

I load a webview in my app and i want when the button is pressed("Login") from javascript to send the data to the function webView ScriptNotify. I managed to achieve this with success in universal 8.1 apps but when i tried it in universal 10 apps i take the data also with success but my problem is when the button is pressed **the login screen freezes** and don't show anything(but i took the data). Can someone help me with my problem? What can i do to solve it?